# OpenVPN "TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed"; possible malicious access tentative

Tags: openvpn, network-security

I have an Ubuntu Server with OpenVPN 2.5.5. Here is the server configuration

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/server/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server/issued/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server/private/server.key  
dh /etc/openvpn/server/dh.pem
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-GCM
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/server/crl.pem
plugin /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so openvpn
```

The server uses iptables to manage input/output traffic. I configured it to allow VPN connection, and I can connect to the server remotely from my Windows PC. I use a certificate (no username/password) + 2 factor authentication.

I have a minor problem (disconnection after a while). I monitored OpenVPN server log to understand the cause, and I noticed this periodic message, even when no one is connected:

```
2024-03-13 08:51:03 us=28396 MULTI: multi_create_instance called
2024-03-13 08:51:03 us=28589 108.181.213.21:10206 Re-using SSL/TLS context
2024-03-13 08:51:03 us=28829 108.181.213.21:10206 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1621 D:1212 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
2024-03-13 08:51:03 us=28881 108.181.213.21:10206 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1621 D:1450 EF:121 EB:406 ET:0 EL:3 ]
2024-03-13 08:51:03 us=28985 108.181.213.21:10206 Local Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1549,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,cipher AES-256-GCM,auth [null-digest],keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-server'
2024-03-13 08:51:03 us=29023 108.181.213.21:10206 Expected Remote Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1549,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,cipher AES-256-GCM,auth [null-digest],keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-client'
2024-03-13 08:51:03 us=29103 108.181.213.21:10206 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]108.181.213.21:10206, sid=6a22eb44 5adb63fe
2024-03-13 08:52:03 us=515281 108.181.213.21:10206 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
2024-03-13 08:52:03 us=515447 108.181.213.21:10206 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
2024-03-13 08:52:03 us=515651 108.181.213.21:10206 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
2024-03-13 08:52:03 us=649600 MULTI: multi_create_instance called
2024-03-13 08:52:03 us=649845 108.181.213.21:10206 Re-using SSL/TLS context
2024-03-13 08:52:03 us=650065 108.181.213.21:10206 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1621 D:1212 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
2024-03-13 08:52:03 us=650131 108.181.213.21:10206 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1621 D:1450 EF:121 EB:406 ET:0 EL:3 ]
2024-03-13 08:52:03 us=650270 108.181.213.21:10206 Local Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1549,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,cipher AES-256-GCM,auth [null-digest],keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-server'
2024-03-13 08:52:03 us=650323 108.181.213.21:10206 Expected Remote Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1549,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,cipher AES-256-GCM,auth [null-digest],keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-client'
2024-03-13 08:52:03 us=650422 108.181.213.21:10206 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]108.181.213.21:10206, sid=6a22eb44 5adb63fe
```

What's happening? Looks like IP 108.181.213.21 is trying to connect to my VPN. Is it so?
Another IP that gave me the same periodic message in the last days is 23.27.211.242. Both IP seems to be related to some gaming thing. Is someone trying to access my server?

If that is the case, what is a good solution (if needed) to better "hide" my server? First thought is to change the standard port.

...or maybe I'm completely misunderstanding the log.